# ERROR: function to_jsonb(text, jsonb) does not exist - POSTGRESQL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I have PostgreSQL v12 and this code works fine for me in this version. I have no idea if this is a version issue or not but I want to use POSTGRESQL v9.4

```
----------------------- Function Start v1.0 ------------------------------
drop function if exists aa_Dev.VDN();
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION aa_dev.VDN()
  RETURNS VOID AS
$$
declare 

    tempp json;

begin

    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS aa_dev.sdg_vdn;

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS aa_dev.sdg_vdn (
        VDN INT,
        skills INT[]
    );
    
    tempp := (select VDN_group from aa_dev.sdg_metadata);

    insert into aa_dev.sdg_vdn (vdn, skills)
    select (jsonb_populate_record(null::aa_dev.sdg_vdn, to_jsonb(t))).*
    from jsonb_each(tempp::jsonb) as t(vdn, skills);


end

$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

----------------- Function Ends ----------------------
select * from aa_dev.VDN();
select * from aa_dev.sdg_vdn;
```

So the error is

```
SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: function to_jsonb(text, jsonb) does not exist
  Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Where: PL/pgSQL function aa_dev.vdn() line 17 at SQL statement
```

How can I eliminate this error and run the function in postgresql 9.4. I have a restriction with this version.

Comment: Old postgresql did not support jsonb. There is nothing you can do except for upgrading your postgresql server

Comment: @mvp Any way I can modify my Query?

Comment: Also, Can you tell me in which version after 9.4 did PostgreSQL start supporting jsonb. @mvp

Comment: 9.4 is no longer supported or maintained anyway. And if you upgrade, you should upgrade to the latest version. So just go for Postgres 13

Answer (score 2):

There is some support to jsonb in version 9.4.  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/functions-json.html

You can instead of `to_jsonb(t)` use `to_json(t)::jsonb`